# Create function with conditional subfunctions

Tags: r

I have a series of functions that clean data from a dataframe (populated with fake data). The functions usually work on individual columns. Sometimes the columns are not present.
I would like to create a function that contains all the subfunctions but obviously each subfunction will only work if the column is present.

***The input***

```
structure(list(HospitalNumber = c(" J6044658\n", " Y6417773\n"
), PatientName = c("  Jargon, Victoria\n", "  Powell, Destiny\n"
), DOB = c("  1943-10-13\n", "  1946-12-29\n"), GeneralPractitioner = c(" Dr\n Martin, Marche\n", 
" Dr\n al-Safi, Lutfiyya\n"), Dateofprocedure = structure(c(14559, 
14045), class = "Date"), ClinicalDetails = c("  Ongoing antral gastritis despite treatment with PPI,Reflux sx\n,High dyshagia OGD - fundic gastritis\n,Chronic diarrhoea/colonic biopsies,Currently on steriod for IgG4 disease\n,Food bolus obstruction\n\n4 specimen\n Nature of specimen:  Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'proximal body lesser curve polyps x4 ',Specimen A- Nature of specimen as stated on request form = 'GREATER CURVE ',Nature of specimen as stated on request form = 'Gastric polyp '\n", 
"  Quadrantic biopsies were taken at\n,OGD - only 3cm sliding hiatus\n\n7 specimen\n Nature of specimen:  Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'RECTAL POLYPS X3 ',Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'fundus polyps x4 ',Nature of specimen as stated on request form = 'DUODENAL BX ',Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'Papilloma at 36 cm oesophagus ',a) Nature of specimen as stated on request form = 'D2 bx x 2' ,Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'Oesophagus 26 cm '\n"
), Macroscopicdescription = c(" 3 specimens collected the largest measuring 3 x 2 x 1 mm and the smallest 2 x 1 x 5 mm\n", 
" 4 specimens collected the largest measuring 4 x 4 x 4 mm and the smallest 5 x 3 x 1 mm\n"
), Histology = c("  Two biopsies consist of small bowel mucosa and are within normal histological limits\n\n", 
"  modified giemsa stain\n,These are biopsies of gastric mucosa ,There is no evidence of coeliac disease\n,The nuclei are hyperchromatic,\n,There is no granulomatous inflammation\n,The appearances are in keeping with a reactive/chemical gastritis,features including basal layer hyperplasia and reactive nucelar changes with underlying\n,These are two biopsies of squamous epithelium within normal limits,fibromuscularisation of the lamina propria and mild chronic inflammation\n,These biopsies of columnar mucosa show focal acute inflammation, moderate chronic inflammation\n\n"
), Diagnosis = c("  Distal transverse colon polyp excision:- tubular adenoma, low grade dysplasia\n,Ileo-caecal valve, biopsies:\n,Stomach antrum biopsies:- normal mucosa\n,- Up to 34 eosinophils per high power field,Stomach, biopsy - Mild chronic inflammation\n", 
"  Rectum, polyp biopsy: - Tubular adenoma with mild dysplasia,- Raised intra-epithelial lymphocytes ,Duodenum, biopsies - within normal histological limits\n,B GI biopsy - DISTAL OESOPHAGUS X2, MID OESO X3, PROX OESO X2\n,Oesophagus, biopsies : - Minimal chronic inflammation,Sigmoid colon, polypectomy: - Tubular adenoma with moderate dysplasia,Oesophagus polyps biopsies:- 2 x papillomas\n,Duodenum biopsies:- normal\n"
)), .Names = c("HospitalNumber", "PatientName", "DOB", "GeneralPractitioner", 
"Dateofprocedure", "ClinicalDetails", "Macroscopicdescription", 
"Histology", "Diagnosis"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

**The aim**

I want the user to be able to name the columns they want to pass in to the function (and have a variable number of parameters in order to do this) so that the function recognises which function to use based on the passed in column name.

**Desired output**

The function should then return the dataframe with all the changes created by the subfunctions.

I had a go as below but suspect there's quite a lot wrong with it.

**The function**

```
ParentFunction<-(x,...){
 args <- list(...)


    pp<-if(!is.null(args[['DOB']])){ DOB_CleanupFunction(DOB)}
    pp<-if(!is.null(args[['AColumn']])){AnotherCleanUpFunction(AColumn)}
    return(pp)

}
```

**Usage**

```
    ParentFunction(pp, DOB='DOB', ProcedureDate='DateofProcedure', ClinicalDetails='ClinicalDetails', Diagnosis='Diagnosis')
```

Comment: Please review [mcve].  The cleaning functions are missing and the sample data frame is unnecessarily large.  it should be possible for someone to run your code if the copy and paste it into their session.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck the cleanup function does not exist. The focus of the question is whether I can create a function that runs other functions. It is the function I am asking for help with and as I can't get it to work then copying it won't help. This is about as MCVE as I can get

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that should work:

```
parent_function <- function(df, cols) {
  if ("DOB" %in% cols) df$DOB <- DOB_CleanupFunction(df$DOB)
  if ("AColumn" %in% cols) df$AColumn <- AnotherCleanupFunction(df$AColumn)
  return(df)
}
```

This function takes two arguments:

- `df` - the data frame that you want to clean
- `cols` - a character vector with the names of the columns you want to clean

A usage example would then be:

```
df_clean <- parent_function(df, cols = c("DOB", "AColumn"))
```

From your problem description it's not apparent why you want the parent function to have an arbitrary number of arguments. IMHO, implementing the parent function with only two arguments is clearer, and should serve the stated purpose.

Comment: Hi @tophcito thanks for the answer.  The specific problem is that the columns in the data frame may not be called DOB so that I want the user to be able to rename the column when entering the parameters (I could ask them to rename in the data frame and then submit parameters but less neat perhaps). I agree on your point of arbitrary number of arguments not being needed however.